# Regarding the proof that similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

The proof is:

$$|\lambda I-P^{-1}AP|=|P^{-1}(\lambda I)P-P^{-1}AP|=|P^{-1}((\lambda I)P-AP)|=|P^{-1}((\lambda I)-A)P)|=|P^{-1}|\cdot|((\lambda I)-A)|\cdot|P|=|\lambda I-A|$$

What I do not understand is why $|\lambda I-P^{-1}AP|=|P^{-1}(\lambda I)P-P^{-1}AP|$ why can we multiple $|\lambda I|=|P^{-1}(\lambda I)P|$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simple:

- $I=P^{-1}P$ and $P^{-1}P=P^{-1}IP$
- Multiply by the scalar $\lambda$, you get: $\lambda I = \lambda P^{-1}IP$
- Scalars can be moved anywhere in the product, result: $\lambda I = P^{-1}(\lambda I)P$

Note that your equality $|\lambda I|=|P^{-1}(\lambda I)P|$ is true but can't be used to answer your question.

Answer (score 7):

$\lambda I=\lambda (P^{-1}IP)=P^{-1}(\lambda I)P$

Answer (score 2):

So $I$ is the identity matrix and $\lambda$ is some number. Now clearly $P^{-1}IP=I$ since the identity matrix commutes with any matrix, i.e. $AI=IA$ for all $A$. Now simply multiply the identity $P^{-1}IP=I$ by $\lambda$.

Also, $|A|$ denotes the determinant of $A$. So the rest follows from the fact that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ and $\det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(A)}$.